# TSQL and Soap Envelope

Tags: sql-server, xml

with the following query Im trying to Read MessageID and DocPurpose. but only Message ID is showing fine.... Can anyone tellme what Im missing? It will be apreciated

```
Declare @XmlData XML =
'<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
  <Header>
    <MessageId>e96d3ee4-5cca-4b3e-be60-d1284a0fb02f</MessageId>
    <Company>CompanyX</Company>
    <Action>http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/services/ReturnOrderInService/create</Action>
    <ConversationId>320034ab-f5ee-41b0-ba35-e0669c2bf1b8</ConversationId>
    <RequestMessageId>e96d3ee4-5cca-4b3e-be60-d1284a0fb02f</RequestMessageId>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <MessageParts>
      <ReturnOrderIn xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/ReturnOrderIn">
        <DocPurpose xmlns="">Original</DocPurpose>
        <SenderId xmlns="">Xcorp</SenderId>
        <SalesTable class="entity" xmlns="">
          <_DocumentHash>63cf8580-92fe-4b17-b15c-8e619eecf71f</_DocumentHash>
          <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
          <CustAccount>147854</CustAccount>
          <LanguageId>en-us</LanguageId>
          <Reservation>None</Reservation>
          <ReturnDeadline>2014-10-10</ReturnDeadline>
          <ReturnReasonCodeId>Reason</ReturnReasonCodeId>
          <SalesName>Stores</SalesName>
          <SalesLine class="entity">
            <DefaultDimension>
              <Values xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/sharedtypes">
                <Value>
                  <Name>Site</Name>
                  <Value>VN</Value>
                </Value>
              </Values>
            </DefaultDimension>
            <ExpectedRetQty>-5</ExpectedRetQty>
            <ItemId>Else</ItemId>
            <Name>Something</Name>
            <PriceUnit>11.00</PriceUnit>
            <SalesQty>-15.00</SalesQty>
          </SalesLine>
        </SalesTable>
      </ReturnOrderIn>
    </MessageParts>
  </Body>
</Envelope>'

Declare @MessageId varchar(50)
    ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message' As a, 
                    'http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/ReturnOrderIn' As b,
                        default 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message')

Select @MessageId =MessageId  from 
    (SELECT 
            t.c.value('a:MessageId[1]', 'varchar(50)') MessageId
    FROM    @XmlData.nodes('/Envelope/Header') AS t(c)) x

Declare @DocPurpose varchar(50)
    ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message' As a, 
                    'http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/ReturnOrderIn' As b,
                        default 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message')

    Select @DocPurpose = DocPurpose from
    (SELECT 
                t.d.value('b:DocPurpose[1]', 'varchar(50)') DocPurpose
        FROM    @XmlData.nodes('Envelope/body/MessageParts/b:ReturnOrderIn') AS t(d))z
    Print 'MessageID>>>>>>' + @MessageId 
    Print @DocPurpose
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<DocPurpose xmlns="">` node is in empty namespace, not the default namespace. Since we can't declare a prefix to map empty namespace URI, just don't declare a `default` in `;WITH XMLNAMESPACES` block. Try this way :

```
Declare @DocPurpose varchar(50)
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES
        ('http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message' As a, 
         'http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/ReturnOrderIn' As b)

Select @DocPurpose = DocPurpose from
(
    SELECT t.d.value('DocPurpose[1]', 'varchar(50)') DocPurpose
    FROM @XmlData.nodes('a:Envelope/a:Body/a:MessageParts/b:ReturnOrderIn') AS t(d)
)z
```

Small thing but matter, you need uppercase `B` for `Body`.